# iPhone app using a web scraper

Tags: ios, web-scraping

I want to make a really simple app that takes the price of Litecoins from this website: http://litecointicker.co.uk/ and just display the price. It will then update every 60 seconds just like the website.

That's all I want it to do. I'm quite inexperienced with Objective-C, and I don't know whether or not this is possible. If you can help, that would be great!

Thank you!

Comment: Have you verified that the website allows you to scrape the site? What's the point of the app? What benefit will your app have over simply going to the website with Safari?

Comment: I haven't verified, but I am only using this for personal use; just seems a little easier than using safari, and I want to learn how to do web scraping for iOS.

Comment: It's certainly possible. Does the site have an XML feed or an API? That would be better than scraping, which tends to be a last-resort option, since it is rather brittle. It may be better for you to do the scrape from your own server, and have the app update from that, so you can fix quickly if the target site changes its HTML.